# Best translation for “confused”: 迷惑，困惑，弄混，搞亂，搞混？

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin, cantonese

This page lists multiple entries for `confused`:

https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php

What's the best translation for `confused` in these contexts:

1) English: "What you just said confused me."

2) English: "I was confused by what she did."

3) Are there general differences among  迷惑，困惑，弄混，搞亂，搞混 (e.g., some are more formal, some are for specific contexts)?

4) For the preceding answers, are there any differences between Mandarin and Cantonese?

Comment: The 4th seems to be a totally unrelated question

Comment: @神秘德里克 Why do you say that? The question is whether the answers vary for Cantonese (e.g., is one term used in Cantonese but not Mandarin), or they're the same for Cantonese and Mandarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

迷惑 and 困惑 can both be verb or adjective

> 迷 (deceive)
>
> 惑 (confuse)
>
> 迷惑 = to confuse (deceive someone and make him confused)

~

> 困 (trap)
>
> 惑(confuse)
>
> 困惑 = to confuse (trap someone in a confusion)

We use 迷惑 for "to confuse" to emphasize the deception part

Example: 用妖言**迷惑**群眾 (妖言**惑**眾) - use lies and rumors **to deceive** and confuse the public

We use 困惑 for "to confuse"  to emphasize the trapping part

Example: 各人不同的口供**困惑**了調查人員 - Everyone’s different stories **confused** investigators (trapped them into a confusion with different stories- but there may or may not be deceptions)

> 弄混，搞亂，搞混 are just different versions of shortened form of "弄/搞 (make-v) 混亂  (confusing-adj)"
>
> e.g. 搞亂局面 = 使局面混亂 (make situation confusing)

~

> *1) English: "What you just said confused me."*

她剛才說的話(**搞得**)我(**混亂了**)

~

> *2) English: "I was confused by what she did."*

我被她剛才說的話(**搞得混亂了**)

~

> *4) For the preceding answers, are there any differences between Mandarin and Cantonese?*

The grammar are the same, the terms may be different.

"你剛才說的話搞得我混亂了" (M)

"你頭先講嘅嘢搞到我好混亂" (C)

"我被你剛才說的話搞得混亂了" (M)

"我被你頭先講嘅嘢搞到好混亂" (C)

Comment: Thanks again for the elaborate answer! Based on what you said, would 搞亂 and 困惑 be the best choices to express the translations of (1) and (2)?

Comment: @Crashalot (1)你刚才说的话让我困惑。(2)我被她所说的搞糊涂了。